# How to return only multiline text comment on the Table_Comment attribute in the wsp_iq.Text_Comment table?

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

could you please help me with the issue below?

I work in Teradata assistant environment. I have table wsp_iq.Text_Comment with text comment attribute called Table_Comment that contains many text records. Few of the text records are multiline and I need to write Teradata SQL code to return multiline records only.

Eg.:
[Table_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c426L.png)

According the description above I need to return only Ids 2 and 4 from Table_Example.

Could you please help me to write Teradata SQL code to be fully functional?

I tried reg_exp, position etc., but still not working. Better to ask more experienced of you.

Comment: Did you try regexp_instr(Text_Comment,'\n')>0

Comment: Sure, I did, unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Perhaps regexp_instr(Text_Comment,'\n|\r')>0. Or provide more detail about what "does not work" means, exactly. Does it miss rows, include rows you don't expect, or what? Consider using CHAR2HEXINT or some other means to understand exactly what the "problem" text values look like.

Comment: regexp_instr(Text_Comment,'\n|\r')>0 works perfectly. Thanks a lot!